# Standard Normal Distribution With Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops, math, logic

I need to fill an array with x values of -2.0 to 2.0 for the normal standard distribution. I am having trouble with the math logic getting it to fill the array. I broke the equation down into 2 parts as well. My current algorithm is to instantiate an array in a for loop with 20 cycles and each cycle run the current value starting at -2.0 in the equation. Then add the final value into the second array and rerun the loop.

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Distribution {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        double mean, omega, pi, e, distribution1, distribution2 , x, y;


        mean = 0.0;
        omega = 1.0;
        pi = 3.14159;
        e = 2.71828;

        double[] xarray;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20, i++)
        {   
            xarray[1] = -2.0;
        distribution1 = -((xarray[2.0]-mean)*(xarray[2.0]-mean))/(2.0*omega);

        distribution2[20] = 1.0 /((sqrt(2*pi)))*e*distribution1;

        xarray[1] = xarray[1] + 0.2;

        }


}

}
```

Comment: also, using constants where index is implied, and e*distribution1 is not the same as `Math.power(e, distribution1)` ... there's a fair number of mistakes here to pick from.

Comment: at least read the [java tutorials for arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I realize now that you just want to fill the array with consecutive [standard normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution) values (as opposed to sampling from the normal distribution). That's even simpler:

```
final double C = 1 / Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI);

final double start = -2.0;
final double end = 2.0;

double[] xarray = new double[20];  // <--    

for (int i = 0; i < xarray.length; i++) {

    double x = start + i * (end - start)/xarray.length;

    xarray[i] = C * Math.exp(-0.5 * x * x);
}
```

The notes above still apply. Note also that the *standard* normal distribution does not have any parameters (i.e. mean and variance), whereas the general [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) does. It's fairly straightforward to generalize the code above.

---

*(Original post)*

I'd use the [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-Muller_transform) for this instead (which maps uniformly distributed variables to normally distributed ones). It's fairly easy to implement:

```
double[] xarray = new double[20];  // <--

for (int i = 0; i < xarray.length; i++) {

    double u1 = Math.random();
    double u2 = Math.random();

    double r = Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(u1));

    xarray[i] = r * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * u2);
}
```

Few things to note:

- We need to initialize the array: `new double[20]`.
- We use `xarray[i]` to refer to the `i`th element (starting from 0) in the array.

Comment: Ok. I have this now to output it:
  System.out.print(xarray1);
But when I do it just prints the memory addresses. How do I output the actual values?

Comment: @user3112609 `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xarray))` (using `java.util.Arrays`).

Comment: Ok, that worked any idea why I am getting a bunch of 0 values after the first output? Looks like this: Also, how could I take this and output as a java graphics drawing using lines?
[0.05399096651318806, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Comment: @user3112609 The code I've posted fills the entire array. If you have an issue with 0s, then it's somewhere else on your end. As for the drawing part, it's impossible for me to summarize it in one comment; I would try Google.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a matter of using  drawLine(0,0,5,Y) drawLine(0,0,10,Y)
drawLine(0,0,15,Y) up to x = 100 for 20 total outputs?